# In mongoDB ,i have to request fo the new feature Compression where can i request for that?

Tags: mongodb

I am using 64-bit MongoDB and am very much miserable about MongoDB on behalf of there is no compression in MongoDB.So, I have request for compression feature in MongoDB.In-order to give a request for it where can i do that?.Is there any specific website available?.Guys If anyone knew about that please help me to do so.

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

To submit a MongoDB feature request you can use: http://jira.mongodb.org/

You can also talk directly to the developers via IRC (irc.freenode.net) in **#mongodb**

As for compression you might also want to look into this ...

http://learnmongo.com/posts/compacting-mongodb-data-files/

Comment: Thanks Justin Jenkins,I am very much excited from your suggestion.I hope this will helpful for me to do so Which i expect.Once again i 'appreciating" your help.

Comment: Second link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Community

Comment: *We're sorry, the page you've requested cannot be found.*